# Laravel - get route parameter value

Tags: laravel, routes

I have got for example this route :

```
Route::get('uzivatel/nove-heslo/{token}/test/{token2}', ['uses' => 'UserController@getNoveHeslo', 'as' => 'admin.new-password']);
```

How can i get the "token" and "token2" parameter?

Comment: Do you put `$token` and `$token2` as parameters of `getNoveHeslo`? Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: But "$token2" will return "test" instead of token2 value.

Comment: It worked fine for me, it shows the value that I'm passing, not "test". Are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I am using Apache. There is no function for this?

Comment: That may be the problem. Have you tried to use [Regular Expression Parameter Constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters)?

Comment: I think, that this is not good solution at all, there is really no function to get the value of parameter? Something like "AwesomeFacade::get('token2')".

Comment: Yes, you can get route parameters, but if you are receiving 'test' as your second token, then it's your URL rewriting that is problematic, and probably not Laravel's fault.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76389/discussion-between-tadeas-jilek-and-ravan).